# How do I get the source media to install Apache Accumulo when I get the error "error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type"?

Tags: java, c++, configuration, installation, bigdata

I am trying to install/build Apache Accumulo.  I am using http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/accumulo/1.9.2/accumulo-1.9.2-src.tar.gz as the installation media.

I ran "mvn package" several times but it would fail because it could not find these files: jni_md.h and jni.h

To overcome this problem, I ran these commands:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64/include/linux/jni_md.h /usr/bin/accumulo-1.9.2/server/native/target/accumulo-native-1.9.2/accumulo-native-1.9.2/javah/

sudo cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64/include/jni.h /usr/bin/accumulo-1.9.2/server/native/target/accumulo-native-1.9.2/accumulo-native-1.9.2/javah/

sudo cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el7_6.x86_64/include/jni.h /usr/bin/accumulo-1.9.2/server/native/target/native/javah/
```

Now when I run "mvn package" I get this:

> [INFO] Apache Accumulo Native Libraries ................... FAILURE [ 
>   3.430 s]
>
> ... g++ -g -fPIC -shared -O3 -Wall -I'/usr/'/include
>   -I'/usr/'/include/linux -Ijavah  -o libaccumulo.so nativeMap/org_apache_accumulo_tserver_NativeMap.cc In file included
>   from /usr/include/stdio.h:74:0,
>                    from javah/jni.h:39,
>                    from javah/org_apache_accumulo_tserver_NativeMap.h:2,
>                    from nativeMap/org_apache_accumulo_tserver_NativeMap.cc:17:
>   /usr/include/libio.h:307:3: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
>   size_t __pad5;    ^ /usr/include/libio.h:311:67: error: ‘size_t’ was
>   not declared in this scope    char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 *
>   sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
>                                                                      ^ /usr/include/libio.h:339:62: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared 
>   typedef __ssize_t __io_read_fn (void *__cookie, char *__buf, size_t
>   __nbytes);
>                                                                 ^ /usr/include/libio.h:348:6: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
>         size_t __n);
>         ^

...

> make: *** [libaccumulo.so] Error 1 [ERROR] Command execution failed.
>   org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 2 (Exit value: 2)
>       at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>       at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)

Some of the files that I have examined say "machine generated" at the top and tell me not to modify them.  I'm concerned that my way around the errors of the missing jni.h and jni_md.h files was not ideal.  I tried setting JAVA_HOME to include their natural locations.  But "mvn package" would not work when I did this.

How do I get the source media to install Apache Accumulo without getting these size_t errors?

Comment: Do you somehow not have a C/C++ installation and/or not in `PATH`? `size_t` is defined in several headers. The most minimalistic of these is `stddef.h`.

Comment: No, I think that the C++ compiler is in PATH.  If I run "whereis c++" I get this:  c++: /usr/bin/c++ /usr/include/c++   When I run "env | grep PATH" I see "/usr/bin/".